# How To Have Default BackColor Value On Custom Button In C#

Tags: c#, custom-controls

I'm making a custom button, and I'm trying to have a default BackColor value for it.
I found I could do that with this code.

```
public override Color BackColor {
    get { return color; }
}
```

But then BackColor isn't editable after placing the button.
I know it's because there's no "set", if you add that when you try edit the property it crashes VS.
This is the code that crashes VS:

```
public override Color BackColor {
    get { return color; }
    set { BackColor = value; Invalidate(); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the value in set to the property itself

```
BackColor = value;
```

Assign value in the setter to the "color" inner field:

```
color = value;
```